# Audio problem on some flash videos

Tags: sound, 64-bit, flash

I'm running Ubuntu 10.10 on my 64-bit laptop, and I have Adobe Flash 10,2,161,22 installed.

The vast majority of the time, I've no problems with flash videos in terms of both video and audio.  But sometimes, I'm having problems with sound.  Here's [a random example](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VuB5ttrid1I). For this one, the first two seconds are fine, but after that, when the interview starts, I can only hear 'squeaks', which I'm guessing is some kind of distortion of the actual sound. There's absolutely no problem with the video throughout. The problem occurs both for Firefox and Google Chrome, the two browsers installed on my computer.

Do I need to install some special audio codec? I couldn't find anything about this by searching on the web.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well as far as i know Adobe flash player for 64 bit is still testing in Ubuntu so it may be buggy or unstable. Hope it answers your question

Comment: Thanks. But do you know if there's some particular reason the audio encoding is different for the video in my question? Or how I could find out? Maybe that could help me track why I'm having the problem.

Comment: Like i said the 64 bit version is yet to be stable so you will have to bear such moments or try installing the 32 bit version and see if it works